# Cross compiling with version 12 of mingw-w64 throws an error, where as version 9.3 works fine

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I'm trying to cross compile some code ([argtable-2.13](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/argtable/argtable/argtable-2.13/argtable2-13.tar.gz), which I cannot change).

```
export cc_path="/usr"
export CFLAGS="-I${cc_path}/i686-w64-mingw32/include"
./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=${cc_path}/i686-w64-mingw32
make CC=${cc_path}/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc AR=${cc_path}/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ar PREFIX=${cc_path}/i686-w64-mingw32 RANLIB=${cc_path}/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ranlib LD={cc_path}/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld STRIP=${cc_path}/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-strip CXX=${cc_path}/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++
```

When I try compiling this code with mingw-w64 on Ubuntu 20.04 (version i686-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 9.3-win32 20200320) it compiles just fine. But when I try the same with mingw-w64 on Ubuntu 23.10 (version i686-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 12-win32), it throws an error.

```
/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/i686-w64-mingw32/include -MT arg_int.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/arg_int.Tpo -c arg_int.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/arg_int.o
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/12-win32/include/mm_malloc.h:29,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/malloc.h:84,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stdlib.h:770,
                 from arg_int.c:28:
arg_int.c:35:37: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
   35 | enum {EMINCOUNT=1,EMAXCOUNT,EBADINT,EOVERFLOW};
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~
arg_int.c: In function ‘strtol0X’:
arg_int.c:60:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘isspace’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   60 |     while (isspace(*ptr))
      |            ^~~~~~~
arg_int.c:33:1: note: include ‘<ctype.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘isspace’
   32 | #include <limits.h>
  +++ |+#include <ctype.h>
   33 | 
arg_int.c:89:8: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘toupper’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   89 |    if (toupper(*ptr++)!=toupper(X))
      |        ^~~~~~~
arg_int.c:89:8: note: include ‘<ctype.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘toupper’
make[2]: *** [Makefile:359: arg_int.lo] Error 1
```

I know why it's throwing an error since enum's cannot have the same name and somewhere with mingw-w64 v12 it's conflicting, but I can't change the code. It's including the file `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/errno.h` which has an enum `EOVERFLOW` defined, but v 9.3 doesn't seem to complain where as v12 has a problem.

I've tried adding `-std=c89` as an option but it doesn't make a difference.

How do I get mingw-w64 version 12 to behave like mingw-w64 version 9.3 in this regard?

Comment: You tagged this with both C++ and C, but the file is named `arg_int.c`.  Is this actually a C++ question or just C?  What is the output of `gcc --version` for your cross-compiler?

Comment: This doesn't look like a complete error. Continue reading its notes. I am pretty sure they can get to get an answer.

Comment: Version 2.13 released Jan 10, 2011. It's very old. Why not use a newer https://github.com/argtable/argtable3?

Comment: @273K it's part of a larger build chain, cannot be changed. Just trying to figure out if it can be fixed. That's the error right there, the enum

Comment: If you could provide a [mcve] and your actual GCC version we might be able to figure out what the problem is.  I can't reproduce the error with the info given because that one line [compiles fine](https://godbolt.org/z/KcT4W53q6) in modern versions of GCC.  Maybe there is a MinGW header somewhere that defines `EBADINT` or something, and it makes your enum invalid.

Comment: You can't fix with such restrictions. MinGW CRT has (relatively new) `#define EOVERFLOW 139 ` in its `errno.h`. argtable3 has fixed that issue: `enum { ARG_ERR_MINCOUNT = 1, ARG_ERR_MAXCOUNT, ARG_ERR_BADINT, ARG_ERR_OVERFLOW, ARG_ERR_BADDOUBLE, ARG_ERR_BADDATE, ARG_ERR_REGNOMATCH };`

Comment: @273K that's correct, it's coming from that file `errno.h`. However I also see that file and the same #define in v9.3 mingw-w64. Why doesn't it complain there? Any way to tell v12 mingw-w64 to ignore this error?

Comment: It's coming from `linux/errno.h`.

Comment: @273K hmm, I thought it was `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/errno.h`. How does one know which one and is there a way to exclude it?

Comment: How? Opening and looking at file contents. `include/errno.h` has `#include <bits/errno.h>` that has `#include <linux/errno.h>`

Comment: The error is coming from `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/12-win32/include/mm_malloc.h:29`, when you open that file line 29 is `#include <errno.h>` and since the `CFLAGS="-I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include"` I'm assuming that's pointing to `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/errno.h`. This `errno.h` file and the `#define EOVERFLOW` is there in both v9.3 and v12 of mingw-w64, my compile syntax is identical, v9.3 compiles, v12 doesn't. Why?

Comment: It doesn't include `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/errno.h` because your command shows the other absolute path `-I/i686-w64-mingw32/include`.

Comment: The usage `-I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include` also would be wrong, and must be `-isystem /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include`

Comment: What do you want from us? If you can't update the library, patch it before building.

Answer (score 1):

This was news to me, but it seems that `errno.h` is allowed to spew custom identifiers starting with `E` all over the standard namespace, as an implementation-defined feature.

C23 7.5:

> Additional macro definitions, beginning with E and a digit or E and an uppercase letter, may also be specified by the implementation.

This is also mentioned in "future library directions". So some versions of the library may define stuff like `EOVERFLOW` as an implementation-defined feature.

Normally adding compiler options like `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors` would strip off non-standard identifiers from standard headers, but here it doesn't make a difference since standard C allows these identifiers to exist.

But notably this also means that such an implementation of `errno.h` cannot be used in strictly conforming programs.

The best work-around is not to use `errno.h` at all - it was always an archaic and poorly designed header, just as using a global error result variable was always bad design from a time long before multi-threading was invented. But sadly, lots of standard functions rely on `errno` so maybe that's not an option.

A possible work-around is just to do `#undef EOVERFLOW`, if you can't rename the enum.

As for why you get different results for different compiler versions, it may be that Mingw switched standard lib along the way. They used to use Microsoft's "CRT" standard lib, but I think(?) they switched out that one somewhere along the way.